# Android BLE Pairing Popup - System and custom app popup appearing

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to pair my bluetooth device with my android phone. I tried calling createBond() method which raises the popup of pairing. While this popup appears, the system popup for pairing the bluetooth also appears in the notification bar. Is there any way to suppress the system popup for pairing in notification bar?

Also, is there a possibility to bypass the pairing dialog and pair the device programmatically? If not, can I directly enter the passkey by setpin() method so that user can just click the pair button?

I tried various method but did not get success. Appreciate the help.